# How to form a 2D dict from a 2D list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Here I'm creating a 2D list where in for every element i have another dictionary defined. This is how i am using that function :

```
b = [[get_dict(x,y) for x in range(a)] for y in  range(b)]
```

where the get_dict function brings the dictionary for that particular point eg.`b[1][1]`

I want to have this in a 2D dictionary instead of list which looks like

```
{ 0 : { 0 : get_dict(0,0)
      { 1 : get dict(0,1)
        .....
       }

{1:    { 0: get_dict(1,0)
        ...
       }
```

Comment: You probably want to add `},` at the of the lines containing `get_dict` of your desired output; otherwise it's no valid dict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my_dict = {x: {y: get_dict(x, y) for y in range(b)} for x in range(a)}
```